# An inequality: $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\le n(x^4+y^4+z^4)$

Tags: inequality

**Question**: Find the smallest possible integer value of $n$, for which the following inequality holds true:-
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\le n(x^4+y^4+z^4)$$
Where $x,y,z \in R $.

---

I used the Cauchy inequality to reduce it to: 
$$(x^4+y^4+z^4)\le n$$
How do I proceed? What are the steps I can take to actually find out the smallest possible integer value of $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since
$$(x^4+y^4+z^4)(1+1+1)\ge (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$$
so
$$n\ge3$$
other hand
$$x=y=z=1\Longrightarrow n=3$$
so
$$n_{min}=3$$

Comment: I believe you mean $n \geq 3$.

Comment: 'n' Should be an integer. Question doesn't ask for 'n' minimum. And how exactly did you get the first inequality?

Comment: The question asked for what value $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\le n(x^4+y^4+z^4)$ holds true, and the answer starts by stating "Since $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\le 3(x^4+y^4+z^4)$ is true, we have blah blah blah"?

Comment: I believe you meant $n_{\min}\leq 3$, because you are asked to find the MINIMUM $n$ and a positive integer $3$ always works.

Comment: Indeed I'm aware this is Cauchy-Schwarz, what I'm talking about is, this answer is not how an answer should be presented. Basically it's directly jumping to the answer without any intermediate step. And do you notice nowhere is Cauchy-Schwarz mentioned?

Comment: @AbelCheung Cauchy inequality is mentioned by the OP in the question itself.  Perhaps the way it is answered can be improved, but it seems to work as a hint anyway.